# Is it important to point the domain to server IP to get them linked?

Tags: domains, dns, nameserver, dns-servers

I am trying to link my domain registerd from `exabytes.com.my` and I want to link it with my server in GoDaddy.

`exabytes.com.my` allowed me to modify nameservers only , I set name servers as :

```
ns1.secureserver.net

ns2.secureserver.net
```

I added my domain and put the same nameservers in GoDaddy server and its still unlinked!

My domain is `http://atrax.com.my/`.

Why? and if it get linked , what if someone else just added my domain name and put nameservers that they can check from any DNS checker , will that be linked?

I am confused right now about this Nameserver thing, I cant add my server IP in `exabytes.com.my` so how will I link the domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `exabytes.com.my` allowed me to modify nameservers only

That is exactly what you need to do. And that is the only thing you need to do.

To find out what NAMESERVERS you need to specify at your registrar, check your account at GoDaddy.

Reference (possibly UK specific?):
https://uk.godaddy.com/help/find-your-nameservers-for-domains-registered-at-other-companies-12318

> I added my domain and put the same nameservers in GoDaddy server and its still unlinked!

When you create your account at GoDaddy you will be prompted to enter your domain. You should not change any NAMESERVERS at GoDaddy (your host).

The NAMESERVERS are where your master DNS records are stored.

Note that changing NAMESERVERS can take up to 48 hours. As this change needs to be propagated around the internet.

> what if someone else just added my domain name and put nameservers that they can check from any DNS checker , will that be linked?

It's technically possible that "someone else" created an account on the same server for the same domain at GoDaddy *before* you did. But this is very unlikely.

Comment: The last question was , lets say i bought the domain and linked it to ns1.secureserver.net and i still didn't link it with the hosting , then someone else goes and gets my nameservers from DNS checker and add them and the domain to his server .. will that work ?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what you mean? But what you appear to be suggesting sounds impossible. "gets my nameservers from DNS checker and add them and the domain to his server" - that bit doesn't seem to make sense? If your domain is linked to `ns1.secureserver.net` then that is where your master DNS records are stored. `ns1.secureserver.net` is also a registered name in DNS and points to a particular server - no one else can use that name (at least if they tried then no one would ever see it).

Comment: They can add your domain name to their server, but again, no one would ever see it because it wouldn't be registered separately in DNS - you have already done that and control the master records.

Answer (score 0):

What you'll need to add an external webhost (GoDaddy) to your new domain name (at Exabytes) is an ['A Record'](https://support.exabytes.com/kb/a3811/add-a-record-in-advanced-dns-zone-editor.aspx).

A Cname record points to another name. If you want your new domain to point to your other domain - just add a Cname record that translates one to another.

Comment: You don't need to use an `A` record at the registrar. You can change the NAMESERVERS to use a different DNS server altogether - which the OP states is the only option offered by their registrar.